# Overwrite value of Play JSON Combinator Writes

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.4

Suppose I have a json writes like this

```
  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "email").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "encryptedPassword").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "id").writeNullable[Long]
    )(unlift(User.unapply))
```

If I don't want to printout the password, and instead just print a string `"hidden"`, how can I achieve this with combinator?

I am looking for a solution that looks similar to this

```
  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "email").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "encryptedPassword").write[String](Writes.pure("hidden")) ~
      (__ \ "id").writeNullable[Long]
    )(unlift(User.unapply))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "email").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "encryptedPassword").write[String](Writes((_: String) => JsString("hidden"))) ~
      (__ \ "id").writeNullable[Long]
    )(unlift(User.unapply))
```

Comment: Thanks @Grisuu. This is the answer I was looking for. However, I found it a better practice to create different classes for different scenario, and only use the default JSON Reads and JSON Writes. It's much cleaner than having to write a bunch of JSON mapping code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
  override def writes(user: User): JsValue = Json.obj(
    "name" -> user.name,
    "email" -> user.email,
    "encryptedPassword" -> "hidden",
    "id" -> user.id
  )
}
```